# Xcode add app to iPhone for testing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, meteor

I have an app build with Meteor like this `meteor build <path> --server <address:port>`. What is the next step to add it to my iPhone for testing?

When I open the myApp.xproject file it saying in Identity section `no matching provisioning profiles found` I did try 'Fix issue' btn, which guided me to make an account etc. But this did not fix it. Is it possible because I haven't paid yet for for my account? I just would like to see how it would work on my iPhone for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you need a developer account to run on an actual device. Pay for the account and you will get development profiles and distribution profiles so you can run on your phone and submit to The App Store. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's a weird way that used to work. It's like a debugging mode but the most recommended way is to do it getting the developer account as Douglas said.

These are the steps:

- Go to Xcode > Preferences and where says Accounts add your apple id. It will ask you for a team name, type your name for example.
- Now go back to Xcode and click on the blue file at the top of the navigator with your project name. Then General.
- The system will ask you about fixing an issue, do it and after a while it will finish.
- Then choose a version available on your device and your iPhone in the device selection.

It worked with some of my classmates, I can't verify it 100% because I have the developer account. Hope it helps.